# What GUI framework should I use?

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks

I'd like a GUI framework that works on both Windows and Linux.

I'm confused because Googling has returned a lot of different ones.

Since I'm coming from a C# background, lots of choices means I don't know which one is the best to use and might start learning one that is discontinued or generally frowned upon by the Java community.

Thanks.

Comment: your googleresults confuse me, because whenever I googled, I found swing and swt, nothing else(except for the discontinued QtJambi)

Comment: @DaVinci, google gives results according to location. I got AWT, swing, BWT, JOGL, and many more.

Comment: awt was the predecessor of swing, JOGL is not about UI and I cannot find anything about BWT?
However, I would suggest you use swing, it's the official Sun/Oracle library and quite good and flexible, but note that it's also quite conservative, you shouldn't expect anything "fancy" from it - there's nothing comparable to WPF in javaland.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also suggest to choose a RCP (Rich Client Platform) rather than just a basic GUI toolkit (such as Swing, SWT, Windows Forms, WPF,...).

This leaves you basically with 2 choices:

- NetBeans Platform (Swing based)
- Eclipse RCP (SWT based)

Comment: For a person that its confused by their google results (even for more experienced programmers) i would still sugest start with the basic ones.

Answer (score 1):

In java the most famous are:

- awt (it was used widely years ago, no more)
- [swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) (IMO the most used)(jdownloader, the topcoder arena are good examples, even the official IDE netbeans have a GUI builder for swing)
- javafx, intended to replace flash like programs.

Comment: I'd add SWT to that list, as it's the base for Eclipse - and unfortunatly everyone seems to use it these days for Java-development…

Comment: I always want to know but not searched, what graphical toolkit was using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) (native Java GUI toolkit, so most popular) or [Qt Jambi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Jambi) (Qt bindings for Java)